# how to run application in android 4.4 and 7?

Tags: android

how to run application in android 4.4 and 7 ?

My application runs on Android 7, but it does not run on Android 4.4 and goes off the application.

When running the application on Android 4.4, there is no special error in logcat but it does not run on Android 4.4 and goes off the application.

How to fix it ?

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.aradteam.persiantoon"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


}
```

And My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="ir.aradteam.persiantoon">

    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="co.ronash.pushe" />
    <permission
        android:name="ir.aradteam.persiantoon.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="ir.aradteam.persiantoon.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />


    <application
        android:name="ir.aradteam.persiantoon.G"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/logo"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="allowBackup,supportsRtl"
        >

        <activity android:name=".SplachScreen.SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="ir.aradteam.persiantoon.ShowVideo.ShowVideoActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name="ir.aradteam.persiantoon.Search.ActivitySearch"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="ir.aradteam.persiantoon.login.ActivityLogin"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="ir.aradteam.persiantoon.Gallery.ActivityGallery"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="ir.aradteam.persiantoon.Comments.ActivityComments"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="ir.aradteam.persiantoon.ShowVideo.PlayVideo"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@style/prograssBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="ir.aradteam.persiantoon.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="zarinpalpayment"
                    android:scheme="return" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <receiver android:name="co.ronash.pushe.receiver.UpdateReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />

                <data
                    android:path="ir.aradteam.persiantoon"
                    android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="ir.aradteam.persiantoon" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <meta-data
            android:name="co.ronash.pushe.token"
            android:value="PUSHE_429459318441" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="co.ronash.pushe.cr"
            android:value="Tm9uZQ==" />

        <receiver android:name="co.ronash.pushe.receiver.UpdateReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />

                <data
                    android:path="ir.aradteam.persiantoon"
                    android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="ir.aradteam.persiantoon" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <meta-data
            android:name="co.ronash.pushe.token"
            android:value="PUSHE_429459318441" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="co.ronash.pushe.cr"
            android:value="Tm9uZQ==" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: add your logcat

Answer (score 1):

Strip it down to the bare minimum, just take one empty activity, no permissions or filters of any kind and see if it works. Then start adding things back.

Also, your `compileSdkVersion` and your `targetSdkVersion` should be the same in your case, and I see you're missing the `buildToolVersion` from your gradle. I think that's now being included in the wrapper or somewhere, but you shouldn't rely on it, declare your own so you can upgrade whenever a new version is out. So the question is, have you tried to put a breakpoint in the Application to see if it even gets spun up ?